# Parse JSON and iterate objects using jq

Tags: json, bash, parsing, jq

```
[ 
{ "id":"1", 
  "metadata":{"version":"1.0","author":"user1"}
},
{ "id":"2", 
  "metadata":{"version":"1.0","author":"user2","timestamp":"2019-02-05"}
},
{ "id":"3", 
  "metadata":{"version":"1.0","author":"user3","price":"10.0"}
}]
```

I am trying to parse the above json (data1.json) using jq, but I am unable to access the metadata object. I will eventually use the metadata object to insert into a database as a string. It can have any number of fields, the structure is not fixed. This is the script that I'm using.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
id=($(jq '.[] | .id' data1.json | tr -d '"'))
metadata=($(jq '.[] | .metadata' data1.json))

n_id=${#id[@]}
n_meta=${#metadata[@]}

echo $n_id 
echo $n_meta 

for (( i=0; i<n_id; i++ )); do
    echo ${metadata[$i]} 
done
```

Expected output:

```
{"version":"1.0","author":"user1"}

{"version":"1.0","author":"user2","timestamp":"2019-02-05"}

{"version":"1.0","author":"user3","price":"10.0"}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the metadata objects, one per line, not wrapped in an array?

```
$ jq -c '.[] | .metadata' data1.json
{"version":"1.0","author":"user1"}
{"version":"1.0","author":"user2","timestamp":"2019-02-05"}
{"version":"1.0","author":"user3","price":"10.0"}
```

But you're already doing just that for your `metadata` array in your shell code. If you want to print that array one per line:

```
printf "%s\n" "${metadata[@]}"
```

To get the lines printed by jq into an array when there are spaces in the object contents:

```
mapfile -t metadata < <(jq -c '.[] | .metadata' data1.json)
```

or

```
while IFS= read -r obj; do metadata+=("$obj"); done < <(jq -c '.[] | .metadata' data1.json)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works!! but I see one small problem, if there is space in one of the values, the object is not stored as expected. For example, if "author":"fname lname" has spaces in all the metadata objects, it breaks off after fname.

Comment: @prathyusha Added a few ways to populate the array that avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [jtc](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc):

If the above content is in the file `foo.json`, you can do:

```
% <foo.json jtc -tc -w '<metadata>l:'
{ "author": "user1", "version": "1.0" }
{ "author": "user2", "timestamp": "2019-02-05", "version": "1.0" }
{ "author": "user3", "price": "10.0", "version": "1.0" }
```

`-tc` means "compact output format"

`-w ..` is the walk path

`<metadata>` match on 'metadata', `l` means label match, `:` means 'all'

Comment: it's better to use `-r` option to ensure single row output for walks. thus the complete answer would be: `while IFS= read -r obj; do metadata+=("$obj"); done < <(jtc -w'<metadata>l:' -r data1.json)`

Answer (score 0):

Why  not just filter your data with jq itself?

```
jq -c '.[] | .metadata' data1.json
```

Please refer to Shawn's answer as I have not accounted for other data.

Comment: I do not know the contents of metadata, it can be anything.. so I can't set the fields like you mentioned.